# Ubuntu 11.10 resource hog?

Tags: 11.10

Ever since I updated to Ubuntu 11.10 my computer has been getting hot and seems like the resources have been more hogged causing my computer to constantly sound like its doing something intense.

I've disabled Unity and am using Gnome session fallback.

Is there anyone else with this issue?

- Best way to explain this is that I feel as if 11.10 is using a LOT more resources than 11.04 did - and I would like to know of a way to make it run smoother and less of a hog

[image: added picture]

Comment: Maybe this question could be converted into something useful with some rewording.

Comment: Try the obvious things like looking at System Monitor to see what process are using what resources, and blow the dust out of any fans with compressed air, etc. You need to add more detail to the question to get a useful answer.

Comment: Edited post so that maybe it could be of use

Comment: Please check your processes page or run `top` in a terminal to see if there is any other weird process taking up your CPU, I see CPU2 at 100% while it seems you are not running anything special, add any further information to the question instead of the comments area please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are issues with 11.10. You can solve some of them by paying close attention to your system, whereas others are very hard to fix. Fortunately, most of these issues are gone Precise Pangolin (to become 12.04 in April) so we have good times ahead. If it's a big problem for you, then I would recommend that you install 10.04 if that's possible, since that will be upgradeable to 12.04 when it's released. Or, if you're a bit more adventurous, you can upgrade/install 12.04 now. It is under development, so you'll have to watch out a little bit when you install upgrades, but there have been rather few issues with it. On both my desktop and laptop, 12.04 is *much* better than 11.10. Battery time on my laptop has gone from 3.5-4 hours to more than 5 hours.

If it's not too big a problem, and you don't feel too adventurous, then I would recommend just waiting a little while and upgrade to 12.04.

Comment: Link to Pangolin?

Comment: Also is 10.04 the 10.04LTS? or is there another one I'm thinking of?

Comment: Yes, 10.04 is an LTS. So will 12.04 be. The daily images for Precise can be downloaded from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/. Please keep in mind that it is a development version.

Comment: All's well, I switched to 12.04 love it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great! Don't forget to report bugs when you encounter them! I think 12.04 will be by far the best version of Ubuntu ever.

Comment: How did the upgrade go? Is Precise stable for you? I am running 10.04 LTS and am thinking of upgrading since I really want to use the new Unity.